# Rotating table and slow query performance

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a very thorny performance problem with a table on SQL Server 2005.

The design dates back a bit and the amount of data the application is processing has grown a lot. Now it is unbearably slow and I need to refactor it some way.

I hope someone can enlighten me on best practices to do it. I have done some research and experiments, leading to several questions and I hope putting them in one posting is not too bad behaviour.

The table in question is of the following structure (some fieldnames obfuscated):

```
CREATE TABLE [Items] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [F1] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [F2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [F3] [int] NULL,
    [amount] [float] NOT NULL,
    [F3] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [valid_from] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [valid_until] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [F4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [F5] [int] NULL,
    [F6] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ('false'),
    [F7] [datetime] NULL,
    [F8] [int] NULL,
    [F9] [int] NULL,
    [F9] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_pnl_korrekturen] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] )
)
```

The records in this table represent monetary amounts that are either valid for a single day or a range of dates. The range is given by the valid_from and valid_until columns. These contain only dates, the time-part is always 00:00:00.

For each day that we process we add about a Million records to this table that have valid_from=valid_until. There is a small set of records with ranges > 1 day. Very small, only about 0.03% of them.

The 1-day items get deleted whenever we are finished processing a days data or when we need to reprocess it. Multi-day items live longer, usually about a year.

Not surprisingly most queries on this table start with selecting a date-range, and then some more criteria:

```
SELECT *
FROM Items
WHERE (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate)
   AND (F1 = @SomeValue)
```

The table has a separate index for valid_from and valid_until. But of course that does not help a lot with a range query like that.

So queries on that table run for Minutes. As they are frequent they make the application virtually unusable.

**Q1:** Is there a best practice for a rotating table with Millions of record per "chapter" where each chapter lives only for a while and then is deleted? Do I need some extra maintenance on this table?

**Q2:** Regarding maintenance. The final structure above has been arrived at through a series of ALTER TABLEs. I do not know how SQL-Server handles those. Do I need to "rebuild" a table at some point?

**Q3:** I tried to create an index that would help SQL-Server take advantage of the fact that most of the records are valid only on a specific day. I added a calculated field and an index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE Items
ADD SingleDay AS (CASE WHEN (valid_from=valid_until) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_proc_pnl_items_valid_from_SingleDay 
ON Items (valid_from, SingleDay)
```

To then query:

```
WHERE ((SingleDay = 1) AND (valid_from = @SomeDate))
   OR ((SingleDay = 0) AND (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate))
```

I looked at the query plans for this and it does use my new index. It is however only quicker if I just do a head-count. The minute I select actual data I don't get any improvement. That is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items 
WHERE (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate)
```

Runs for about a minute.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items 
WHERE ((SingleDay = 1) AND (valid_from = @SomeDate))
   OR ((SingleDay = 0) AND (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate))
```

returns almost instantly.

But

```
SELECT ID FROM Items 
WHERE (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate)
```

and

```
SELECT ID FROM Items 
WHERE ((SingleDay = 1) AND (valid_from = @SomeDate))
   OR ((SingleDay = 0) AND (valid_from <= @SomeDate) AND (valid_until >= @SomeDate))
```

Both take about a minute.

Can someone explain that to me, or give me an advice on how to investigate that?

Comment: You may ask questions like this on http://DBA.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "having" instead of where